# Trouble with printing a double from an array

Tags: c, arrays, int, double

My program is to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression, and then evaluate the postfix expression.

The expression should be enclosed in parentheses. Letters may be used, and if there are letters, they will be converted into their numerical equivalents `(e.g. 'A' = 1, 'B' = 2, 'C' = 3, and 'a' = -1, 'b' = -2, 'c' = -3)` and the result will be a number.

Everything works perfectly, except for one thing: the result itself.

My result is in an array (`result[]`) and I should be using a double array (for dividing). The thing is, if I set the result array as an `int` array, the program works fine (except for the divisions, of course. It returns the floor), but when I change the array into a double array, it gives wrong answers.

I've tried lots of different solutions, including typecasting and rearranging the code. Could someone figure it out please? :(

Here is my code for the functions that might be related to the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

typedef struct stack
{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
} stack;

int priority(char);
void init(stack*);
int empty(stack*);
int full(stack*);
char pop(stack*);
void push(stack*, char);
char top(stack*);
void add(char*, char, int);
void keyboard();
void read_file();
int change(char);
void pushYO(double);
double popYO();

stack s;
char x;
int i, token, topYO = -1;
double result[MAX];

char infx[MAX], filepath[MAX];

void main()
{
    char choice;
    init(&s);
    system("CLS");
    printf("[1] Keyboard \n[2] Read from text file \n[3] Exit \n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if(choice != '1' && choice != '2' && choice != '3')
    {
        main();
    }
    else if(choice == '1')
    {
        keyboard();
    }
    else if(choice == '2')
    {
        read_file();
    }
    else if(choice == '3')
    {
        printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}


void keyboard()
{
    int z = 0, count = 0, form = -1, paren = 0;
    double one, two, three = 1;
    char pofx[MAX];
    char choice;
    FILE *text = fopen("text.txt", "a");
    printf("Enter infix expression (in parentheses): ");
    scanf("%s", &infx);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(infx); i++)
    {
        if((token = infx[i]) != '\n')
        {
            printf("%c", token);
            fprintf(text, "%c", token);
            if(isalnum(token))
            {
                form++;
            }
            else
            {

                if(token == '(')
                {
                    paren++;

                }
                else if(token == ')')
                {
                    paren--;
                }
                else
                {
                    form--;
                }

            }

            if (paren < 0)
            {
                printf("\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
                fprintf(text, "\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
                fclose(text);
                printf("\nRun again? \n[1] Yes \n[any other key] No\n");
                scanf("%c", &choice);
                scanf("%c", &choice);
                if(choice == '1')
                {
                    main();
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }


            if(isalnum(token))
            {
                add(pofx, token, count);
                count++;
            }
            else
            if(token == '(')
               {
                    push(&s, '(');
               }
               else
               {
                   if(token == ')')
                   while((x = pop(&s)) != '(')
                         {
                             add(pofx, x, count);
                             count++;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if(token == '^')
                             {
                                 push(&s, token);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 while(priority(token) <= priority(top(&s)) && !empty(&s))
                                 {
                                     x = pop(&s);
                                     add(pofx, x, count);
                                     count++;
                                 }
                                 push(&s, token);
                             }
                         }
                }
        }
        else
        {
        while(!empty(&s))
        {
            x = pop(&s);
            add(pofx, x, count);
            count++;
        }

        }
    }

    printf("\n\nPostfix: %s \n\n", pofx);
    fprintf(text, "\n\nPostfix: %s\n\n", pofx);

    if(form != 0 || paren != 0)
    {
        printf("Error! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n\n");
        fprintf(text, "Error! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n\n");
        fclose(text);
        printf("\nRun again? \n[1] Yes \n[any other key] No\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        if(choice == '1')
        {
            main();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        while((token = pofx[z++]) != '\0')
        {
            three = 1;
            if(!isdigit(token) && !isalpha(token))
            {
                two = popYO();
                one = popYO();

                switch(token)
                {
                    case '+':
                    pushYO((one+two)); break;
                    case '-':
                    pushYO((one-two)); break;
                    case '*':
                    pushYO((one*two)); break;
                    case '/':
                    pushYO((one/two)); break;
                    case '^':
                    if (two > 0)
                    {
                    for(i=0;i<two;i++)
                    {
                        three = three * one;
                    }
                    pushYO(three);
                    three = 1; break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    for(i=0;i<(two-(2*two));i++)
                    {
                        three = three * one;
                    }
                    pushYO((1/three));
                    three = 1; break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else if(isalpha(token))
            {
                if(isupper(token))
                {
                    pushYO((token - '@'));
                }

                if(islower(token))
                {
                    pushYO((token - change(token)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pushYO((token - '0'));
            }
        }

        printf("Result: %d\n-----------------\n", result[topYO]);
        fprintf(text, "Result: %d\n-----------------\n", result[topYO]);
        fclose(text);

    }

    fclose(text);
    printf("\nRun again? \n[1] Yes \n[any other key] No\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        if(choice == '1')
        {
            main();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
            exit(0);
        }

}


void read_file() //reads from text file, does the same thing
{
//code here
}


int priority(char x)
{
    if(x == '(')
    {
        return(0);
    }
    if(x == '+' || x == '-')
    {
        return(1);
    }
    if(x == '*' || x == '/')
    {
        return(2);
    }
    if(x == '^')
    {
        return(3);
    }
    return(4);
}


void init(stack *s)
{
   s->top=-1;
}


int empty(stack *s)
{
    if(s->top==-1)
 return(1);
    else
 return(0);
}


int full(stack *s)
{
    if(s->top==MAX-1)
 return(1);
    else
 return(0);
}


void push(stack *s, char x)
{
  s->top=s->top+1;
  s->data[s->top]=x;
}


char pop(stack *s)
{
   int x;
   x=s->data[s->top];
   s->top=s->top-1;
   return(x);
}


char top(stack *s)
{
   return(s->data[s->top]);
}


void pushYO (double x)
{
 result[++topYO] = x;
}


double popYO ()
{
 return(result[topYO--]);
}


void add(char* s, char c, int count)
{
        s[count] = c;
        s[count+1] = '\0';
}


int change(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
        return(98); break;
        case 'b':
        return(100); break;
        case 'c':
        return(102); break;
        case 'd':
        return(104); break;
        case 'e':
        return(106); break;
        case 'f':
        return(108); break;
        case 'g':
        return(110); break;
        case 'h':
        return(112); break;
        case 'i':
        return(114); break;
        case 'j':
        return(116); break;
        case 'k':
        return(118); break;
        case 'l':
        return(120); break;
        case 'm':
        return(122); break;
        case 'n':
        return(124); break;
        case 'o':
        return(126); break;
        case 'p':
        return(128); break;
        case 'q':
        return(130); break;
        case 'r':
        return(132); break;
        case 's':
        return(134); break;
        case 't':
        return(136); break;
        case 'u':
        return(138); break;
        case 'v':
        return(140); break;
        case 'w':
        return(142); break;
        case 'x':
        return(144); break;
        case 'y':
        return(146); break;
        case 'z':
        return(148); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C.

Comment: @H2CO3 the whole program works fine with void main()

Comment: Quick guess: Do you need to update the `printf` format specifier to `%g` or some such when printing the `double` result?

Comment: @kei101895: The format specifier `%d` is for printing signed integers. The format specifiers `%e`, `%f` and `%g` are for `floats` and `doubles` in exponential (`8.325e+02`), floating-point (`832.5`) and "general" representation, which is the shorter of the two. `printf` is a so-called variadic function; it is special in its treatment of all arguments after the format string. The specifiers must correspond to the type of the arguments. Compiler warnings should tell you about mismatches.

Comment: i just tried using `%g` and it worked XD thank you so much! :D and thanks for the additional info :D @MOehm

Comment: @kei101895 I didn't say it didn't work. I said it's not valid C.

Comment: @H2CO3 thinking about it now, it should be `int main` right?

Comment: @kei101895 Yes, it should. (Unfortunately, many compilers don't enforce it, so normally `void main()` compiles and runs fine too, but it's better to stick to the standard anyway.)